# Not all form errors rendered in custom form field

Tags: php, symfony

A Symfony 4 application has a User entity using Joined InheritanceType with types `Admin`, `Staff` and `Volunteer`. The `Staff` entity has a OneToOne relationship with an `Organization` entity. So the Organization form type includes a child `staff`, which has a custom form type `NewUserType`. (Relevant excerpts appear below.) If an empty `OrganizationType` form is submitted all of the expected form errors are rendered EXCEPT the name and email errors. The `password` form error field of `NewUserType` IS rendered. Symfony's profiler does not show errors for name or email.  `error_bubbling` in `NewUserType` makes no difference. `@Assert\Valid` on the `staff` property of Organization entity makes no difference.

registerOrganization:

```
    public function registerOrganiztion(Request $request) {
        $form = $this->createForm(OrganizationType::class);
        $templates = [
            'Registration/organization.html.twig',
            'Registration/new_user.html.twig',
            'Registration/focuses.html.twig',
        ];
    ...
        return $this->render('Default/formTemplates.html.twig', [
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'headerText' => 'Add an organization',
                    'userHeader' => 'Staff Member',
                    'orgHeader' => 'Organization',
                    'focusHeader' => "Organization's Focus",
                    'templates' => $templates,
        ]);
    }
```

new_user.html.twig:

```
{% if form.staff is defined %}{% set user = form.staff %}{% else %}{% set user = form %}{% endif %}
<div class="text-center text-bold">
    {{ userHeader }}
</div>
{{ form_row(user.fname) }}
{{ form_row(user.sname) }}
{{ form_row(user.email) }}
{{ form_row(user.plainPassword.first) }}
{{ form_row(user.plainPassword.second) }}
```

OrganizationType:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
    ...
                ->add('staff', NewUserType::class)
    }
```

NewUserType:

```
class NewUserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('sname', null, [
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'mb-2',
                        'size' => '15',
                    ],
                    'label' => 'Last name: ',
                    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'mr-2'],
                ])
                ->add('fname', null, [
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'mb-2',
                        'size' => '15',
                    ],
                    'label' => 'First name: ',
                    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'mr-2'],
                ])
                ->add('email', null, [
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'mb-2',
                        'size' => '15',
                    ],
                    'label' => 'Email: ',
                    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'mr-2'],
                ])
                ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
                    'type' => PasswordType::class,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'constraints' => [new NotBlank(['message' => "Password may not empty"])],
                    'invalid_message' => 'Passwords do not match',
                    'first_options' => [
                        'attr' => [
                            'class' => 'mb-2',
                            'size' => '15',
                        ],
                        'label' => 'Password:',
                        'label_attr' => ['class' => 'mr-2'],
                        'required' => true,
                    ],
                    'second_options' => [
                        'attr' => [
                            'class' => 'mb-2',
                            'size' => '15',
                        ],
                        'label' => 'Confirm:',
                        'label_attr' => ['class' => 'mr-2'],
                        'required' => true,
                    ],
                ))
        ;
        if (Volunteer::class === $options['data_class']) {
            $builder
                    ->add('focuses', FocusFieldType::class)
                    ->add('skills', SkillFieldType::class)
            ;
        }
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Staff::class,
            'required' => false,
            'error_bubbling' => true,
        ]);
    }

}
```

Organization entity

```
/**
 * Organization
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="organization")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Organization
{
...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Staff", inversedBy="organization")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="staff_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    protected $staff;
...
}
```

Staff entity

```
/**
 * Staff
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="staff")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Staff extends User
{
...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Organization", mappedBy="staff")
     */
    protected $organization;

    public function getOrganization()
    {
        return $this->organization;
    }

    public function setOrganization(Organization $organization = null)
    {
        $this->organization = $organization;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know why the name & email form errors are not rendered, they can be forced by adding the constraint to the form type. Just need then to remove the `@Assert\...` from those fields in the User entity.